# Error while creating unique index in Oracle: ORA-01452

Tags: oracle, indexing

I had a compound unique index in my table, but due to business reasons, I had to take one of the columns out of the index. So I dropped the index. Now, with the reduced number of columns, it throws error while creating the index: ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found.

Previously the index had an additional column and everything was working fine.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MGRRS.ITRCHESS ON MGRRS.TTRCHESS (MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG)  TABLESPACE IMGRRS  LOCAL
                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
```

Note 1: Please note that I have not dropped the column from the table.

Comment: you already have duplicate data.. you should first get rid of it

Comment: _due to business reasons_ perhaps you can make the index non-unique?

Comment: @samantarighpeima - they did not have duplicate data. If we have a compound index on five columns we can have multiple instances of the same values in four columns provided **the combinations of all five columns are distinct**.

Comment: What combination of columns is unique is ultimately a question for the business. This is why we have entity models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a unique index on multiple columns all the combinations of those columns must be unique. That is, for a compound index on five columns we can have multiple instances of the same values in four columns provided the fifth column contains distinct values to give unique combinations across all five columns.

What has happened in your case is that you have dropped a column from your index *"due to business reasons"*. This means you have lost the column which gave you the unique combinations. Consequently you cannot build a unique index on the remaining four columns.

Your options:

1. Reinstate the dropped column into the index. This may not be practical, depending on the business driver that lead to this situation.
2. Identify the records which have shared combinations [as @PhilippeMarschall shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429491/146325), and update or delete them. This seems to be to be the least desirable option.
3. Create a non-unique index, if you need something for performance reasons. You should run some tests.
4. Don't bother with an index. Do this if the index was not satisfying a performance requirement.

This is as much a political problem as a technical problem. It seems like somebody has come up with a proposal - *"Jay from Marketing says we must drop COLUMN_23 from the index"* - but the impact analysis, all the other things which need to change, has not been completed properly.

So we can offer suggestions but we cannot provide solutions. We don't know why you had a unique index in the first place nor why somebody decided you needed to remove one of the columns from the index. It's your business logic, your data model and your application: only you can decide on the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are having duplicate data, you can find it using

```sql
SELECT MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG
FROM MGRRS.ITRCHESS
GROUP BY MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: The problem is, the OP didn't have duplicate data but then they dropped a column and now the remaining columns are no longer unique combinations. So once the have identified the duplicates what are they going to do?

Comment: Ok, just for clarification, we have not dropped the column from the table, we just removed the index which included the column.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01452 means that the combination of the fields proposed for the index is not unique. You cannot create a UNIQUE index on a combination of columns which is not unique.

You originally had five columns in your index, and the combination of those columns was unique.

You removed one of the fields from the index. Now, the combination of the four fields in the index (MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG) is not unique.

Your choices are:

1. Put the field you removed back into the index.
2. Remove the word `UNIQUE` from the index definition:

   `CREATE INDEX MGRRS.ITRCHESS
      ON MGRRS.TTRCHESS (MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG)
      TABLESPACE IMGRRS
      LOCAL`
3. Delete rows from the table so that there is only one row in the table for each combination of (MHYSTU, MAJUSDESK, DATSNAQ, TIMESSDG).

Best of luck.